# Normalizing Excel Tables

Tags: database, excel, ms-access-2010, database-normalization

How do I create a normalized database from this Excel file?  I have an Excel table with unit numbers across the top and the steps of the units listed down the left side.  Right now people put an "x" in the cell when they are done with a step for a certain unit.  Right now when we decide to do another unit we add one more number on the top.

How do I make this into a normalized Access database?  I assume it needs at least two tables: "Steps" and "Units."

The bigger question, how do I present the form for data entry?  A cross tab query cannot be used to enter data in Access.  People are so used to entering their "x" in this Excel sheet with unit number at the top and pieces down the left side.  How do I make something similar or just as easy to use in Access?

```
Units   1 2 3 4 5
Molded  x x x x x
Bolted  x x  x
Painted x x x
Packed  x
```

Comment: Normalized may have been the wrong word to use.  I am trying to create a new database in Access that mimics this Excel sheet.  I assume I need a table for "Unit Numbers" and another table for "Pieces."

My first question is how to combine these two tables so that I support correct database normalization practices.

My second question is how do I allow users to enter their "x" or completed status in a view that looks very similar to the original spreadsheet or is possibly even better.

Comment: This question seems overly broad, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I edited the question to try to make it more clear.  I couldn't add a picture of the Excel sheet so I tried to include something similar at the end of my question.

Comment: Your question is still unlikely to generate an answer, it falls into "I have not done any research and I want you to help me build a perfect tool for my needs"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tblUnit
UnitID, UnitName
1, Unit1
2, Unit2
3, Unit3
4, Unit4
5, Unit5

tblPiece
PieceID,PieceName
1, Molded
2, Bolted
3, Painted
4, Packed

tblUnitPiece
UnitPieceID, UnitID, PieceID
1, 1, 1
2, 1, 2
3, 1, 3
4, 1, 4
5, 2, 1
6, 2, 2
7, 2, 3
8, 3, 1
9, 3, 3
10, 4, 1
11, 4, 2
12, 5, 1
```

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense.  This is a many to many relationship between the unit numbers and the steps required.  That means there needs to be a third table where that information is combined and where I can put a status.  That is what I was looking for.

Excel users seem to use this design a lot and I am glad it can easily be translated into a database format.

Is there an easy way for users to enter the status in Access?  I haven't been able to create anything in Access that looks the way Excel does.

Comment: Add a 'Status' field to tblUnitPiece, set up the relationships between the two tables, create a query using the three tables with whatever fields you want, then create a form based on that query. Users can use that form to input the status field.

Comment: I shouldn't have asked two questions in one post.  The first question was answered.  I posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/19300461/2820783 to clarify the 2nd question and provide more details.  Thank you Dick for answering my question and for being patient with a new person in this forum.