# 2d form for data entry in Access

Tags: forms, excel, ms-access-2010

I'm using Access 2010 and I would like to create a form where useres can enter data much like they can in an Excel format.  The users need to enter a date when a step is complete for a specific unit.

In Excel the units run aross the top row, the steps run down the left column.  In the cell where the unit and step meet, you put a date when it is done.  In Access it is much harder to create a form that looks like this (at least it has been for me so far).  I tried to use a crosstab query, but you cannot enter information into a crosstab query.  I can do a massive form listing every combination of units and steps, but there are over 50 units and each one has 63 steps.  I don't want users to have to look through a form with over 3,000 lines in it just to enter a date completed.

This definitely feels like something we should be using a database for instead of an Excel spreadsheet.  I have the format for the back end tables to hold the data.  My problem is how to create a form that is easy for the user to enter the dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have three options. First, you could build the form from scratch, which you've already admitted would suck. And it would take a lot of VBA to get the data in the right place. Second, you could automate Excel - it's the same as the first method but you don't have to build the form. You would populate an Excel spreadsheet and write the changes back to the database. This is not a trivial task and I don't recommend it.

The third option is to throw away the idea that you want to do this in a grid. You've probably been doing it in Excel and to the extent that you replicate that, your users will be happy and comfortable. Moving to a database gives you benefits, but there are costs. This is one of the costs.

So create a form with a dropdown containing all of the units. When a unit is selected, populate a subform (datasheet view) listing all of the procedures and dates. The user can then select the unit, and fill in the date next to whichever procedures he wants. Then he can select another unit and do the same thing. If you set it up right, your data will flow to the tables automatically and you'll get all the benefits of data validation, input masks, relationships, and whatever else you're using at the table level.

I know that's not what you were looking for, but I think it's the best way forward.

Comment: I like the dropdown boxes.  It won't look exactly like the old Excel sheets, but the dropdowns sounds like a farily easy and intuitive way for users to enter their dates.  
I've seen some of the code for your first two options and we just don't need that right now.  This is our first step from Excel to a database structure and we need to make it as simple and reliable as possible.  Thank you again for your help.  Getting into databases is a whole new world.